# What comfrey should be used for what purpose?

Tags: comfrey

I know there's a lot of bockings of comfrey, but what one is used for what purpose?

Comment: Welcome back! Did you read the comments under your _first_ question? I recommend you add a lot more details or this may be considered a duplicate by the community. It would also be an option to make the previous one clearer via an [edit].

Comment: it's hard to find the chart describing the purposes of each.

Comment: So you expect the community to do your research? I am quite sure that the knowledge isn’t readily available in our user base. You do realize that this is like a niche in a niche topic?

Comment: leave it open until answered, maybe someone will take it on

Comment: This is not how the SE system works, as you well know. We won’t circumvent the mechanisms by waiting for an answer and then closing. The basic rule is “is this an on-topic question with a reasonably limited scope and enough detail to be answered by the community” - as there are 21 different cultivars (iirc), this can be seen as “too broad”. Feel free to edit the question; for now, I am closing it after the discussion above.